# How do I stop wxhaskell from beeping on enter in text controls?

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I've played around with `processEnter`, `on command`, and `on anyKey` with `textEntry` to no avail. I've been looking through the massive amount of documentation for wx-core, but I don't see anything that'll help. I'm using wxhaskell 0.13.2.1 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html) style to have a chance of capturing the Enter key in a `wxTextCtrl`. If you don't use it, this key is used for activating the default dialog button -- or beeping, under Windows, if there is no such button.